# An unusual floating point rounding error in Unity/C#?

Tags: unity-game-engine, precision, parsefloat

I am using an asset from the Unity Asset Store called World Map Strategy Kit to work on a board game. The kit uses a list of Vector2's with values ranging from -0.5 to +0.5 to determine the borders of provinces/countries on my map.

I am working to read SVG paths and convert them into the lists of points that WMSK inputs.

Basically, without giving you my entire 40 line parse method, I have a setup like below:

```
string raw = "1213.6788";
float x = float.Parse(raw);
float y = float.Parse(raw);
Vector2 a = new Vector2 (x, y);
Debug.Log(a);
```

It consistently rounds the result to 1213.7.

At first I thought it might just be a quirk with float's Parse method, so I wrote an adapted version shown below:

```
string raw = "1213.6788";
float x = (float)double.Parse(raw);
float y = (float)double.Parse(raw);
Vector2 a = new Vector2 (x, y);
Debug.Log(a);
```

Same thing. It rounds to the nearest tenth.

I've noticed something similar below:

```
string rawX = "1213.6788";
string rawY = "891.7";
float x = (float)double.Parse(raw);
float y = (float)double.Parse(raw);
Vector2 a = new Vector2 (x, y);
int tw = 2500;
int th = 1250;
Vector2 translated = new Vector2 ();
translated.x = (a.x - tw * 0.5f + 0.5f) / tw;
translated.x = (a.y - th * 0.5f + 0.5f) / th;
Debug.Log(a);
```

The output now is: 
    (0.0, 0.2)

Which is, again, rounding it to the nearest tenth. I can accept a decent degree of inaccuracy, but this is simply unacceptable -- I am trying to translate the coordinates from a 2500×1250 coordinate system into a 1×1 coordinate system ranging from -0.5 to +0.5. I expect most coordinates to require 3-5 decimal points of information to store it properly.

In no programming language I have worked with -- even Java -- have floating point numbers periodically and consistently rounded to the nearest tenth. It's just not something they typically do in my experience.

So the question is: what am I doing wrong? I mean, surely it is possible to parse the information into a float WITHOUT losing almost all of my decimal places of info?

Could it somehow be my computer (I have a relatively weak and archaic laptop, 1 GHz Intel CPU with 2 GB of RAM from 2010 -- yes, I know I need an upgrade)?

Or is it Unity-specific? Could it be the Vector2 data structure causing the loss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity's default `VectorX.ToString()` (used when converting to text to show in your `Debug.Log()` calls) uses tenths as it's max precision.

To have more precision, simply call `.ToString()` with a custom format: For example, to display with thousands precision, use `Debug.Log(yourVectorX.ToString("F4"));`

NOTE: The underlying value should be correct; it's just being *displayed as rounded* in the text.

Comment: This might seem a stupid question, but I haven't extensively used the ToString with custom formats (the method argument takes a string apparently), so would you be so kind as to give me an example of rounding to 5 decimal places?

Comment: @the_OTHER_DJMethaneMan Was already editing with 4-decimal example while you typed your question. Should be enough for you to figure out 5-decimal format =P... For other styles of formatting; well, that's a different question, and there are more appropriate questions already asked here on SO for `string.Format` and it's many format styles; as well as google.

Comment: Yeah, I'm already familiar with string.Format -- I've used a variant of it in every language I've used, C# included ;-) Thanks for the answer, sorry for the inconvenience.